# C# Entity Framework "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, targetinvocationexception

I'm building a simple login form using VS2015, C#, SQLite DB and entity Framework (under .net framework 4)

when I enter a valid user and password I get this exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

this is my DB :
http://www11.0zz0.com/2016/09/03/23/934209903.png

this is my User Class : 
http://www11.0zz0.com/2016/09/03/23/937963117.png

this is the exception :
http://www11.0zz0.com/2016/09/03/23/381133631.png
http://www11.0zz0.com/2016/09/03/23/355831822.png

I tried everything i know .. but i did not succeeded
Does any one know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: In the 3rd screen shot, the exception has an inner exception. Does the inner exception provide more information?

Comment: @robor78 no .. only this {"Specified cast is not valid."}

Comment: this is a guess, change admin.User1.Equals(u) to admin.User1 == u (like you do for the password)

Comment: changing **Equals()** with **==** didn't work

Comment: another guess, in DB the password is VARCHAR(50), how long is p = Encryption.SHA1Encode(p)

Comment: In the DB, can the IsAdmin field be null? Are there records in the DB with IsAdmin null? The model requires a non-nullable IsAdmin.

Comment: same probleme when setting the VARCHAR(100) the encrypted password is not that long ... , And
No its not null it have a default value '0'

Comment: I'm out of guesses :( Generally "specified cast is not valid" indicates type in database does not match type in model

Comment: Thank you @robor78 .. I'll try to verify the data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The type **BOOLEAN** in SQLite is not very compatible with C# type 'bool' ... I have changed it to **int** instead and it worked as magic.
Thank you mr [robor78](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572332/robor78)